# Once a week \ Once in a week

Tags: sentence-construction

> The dog is given food **once a day \ once in a day.**
>
> We get a day off **a week \ in a week.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The format of "once a `<time unit>`" indicates a frequency with which something occurs.  "My wife gets her hair done once a month."

So used like this, you should say:

> The dog is given food once a day.
>
> We get a day off once a week.

You can use "in a week", but it changes the meaning here:

> We get a day off in a week.

This no longer talks of frequency but in a time frame.  Literally, in a week's time, we get a day off.  This implies a one-time thing and not a reoccurent event.

Similarly you could write:

> The dog is given food in a day.

This talks of a time frame, so literally, in a day's time, the dog is given food.  I presume though that this is not the intended meaning here though, so the former would be better suited here.

Comment: "in a day" means a day from now, but "once in a day" means the same thing as 'once a day"

Comment: @DavidSiegel "once in a day" is mixing "once a day" and "in a day".  From an idiomatic standpoint, it's wrong.   It should be one or the other.

Comment: I must disagree. "Once in a day" was once the standard form, which was elided to "Once a day.  We still see this form in "once in a blue moon" and "once in a while"  and it was not uncommon in British writing of the 1st half of the 20th century, particularly for longer periods "once in a month," or "Once in a quarter"  or 'once in a thousand years". I see this in novels of that period, such as those of Austin Freeman.

Comment: Compare the well-known Emerson quote:“If the stars should appear one night in a thousand years, how would men believe and adore" https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/54383-if-the-stars-should-appear-one-night-in-a-thousand

Comment: @DavidSiegel If someone told you that they give food to their dog once in a day, it's *idiomatically* incorrect.  The fact that it was once used doesn't mean that if you used "thou", "thy", and "thine", it would be correct.  In the interests of teaching proper speech to a non-native speaker, while you can say it was once valid, you don't encourage them to say it that way.

Answer (score 0):

"Once a day" or "once a week" is the more usual, more idiomatic construction. The other sounds a bit odd, or old-fashioned, but is not wrong.